# How can I delete a file from download directory?

Tags: java, android, file, download, delete-file

I tried many ways, but can't delete the file.

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File file = new File(path,"test.txt");

boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

This code is bad as well!
Can somebody help me?

Comment: A few questions...  Does the file exist (`boolean exists = file.exists();`)?  Does the manifest have `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

Comment: Yes, the file exist, and the manifest have this permission, and read_phone_state too!

Comment: If you use the following, what is the logcat output?  `File path = Environment
.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File file = new File(path, "test.txt");

boolean fileExists = file.exists();
boolean isDirectory = file.isDirectory();
boolean canWrite = file.canWrite();
boolean deleted = file.delete();

Log.i(TAG,
String.format(
"File %s does%s exist, is%s a directy, is%s writable, and has%s been deleted.",
file.getAbsolutePath(), fileExists ? "" : " not",
isDirectory ? "" : " not", canWrite ? "" : " not",
deleted ? "" : " not"));`

Comment: 11-24 10:59:25.326: I/(7288): File /mnt/sdcard/Download/teszt.txt does exist, is not a directy, is writable, and has been deleted.

Comment: so the file was deleted?

Comment: No, it's still there, in the downloads folder

Comment: Any other idea to solve the problem?

Comment: what I find most interesting is the `file.delete();` method reports that it was deleted (returns `true`).  How do you know it was not deleted?  Also, if you try deleting a different file, does that different file get deleted?

Comment: No, i tried delete some other kind of files, and  after the file.delete(); method, the files are at the same place, and I can easily open them!